# R: How to obtain difference in weeks between a “POSIXlt” date and the first occurrence of a "POSIXlt" date from the same vector.

Tags: r, difftime

I have a data frame with over a million rows of data (agents and call metrics aggregated by day). Each agent is listed multiple times because they handle calls (d1$Calls) across multiple queues each day. I want to identify the number of weeks an agent has been in the field. I would normally be able to do this using "difftime" to obtain the difference between an agent’s start date (d1$Start) and the interaction date (d1$Interaction) for any given day:

```
floor(difftime(d1$Interaction,d1$Start,units='weeks'))
```

However, my system’s start dates are unreliable often resulting in negative weeks:

```
dput(d1)
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("a123", "b123"), class = "factor"), QUEUE = structure(c(9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("MHEK", "MMED", 
"MMEF", "MMEM", "MNEM", "MSED", "MSEE", "MSEK", "MSEP"), class = "factor"), 
Calls = c(1L, 4L, 25L, 14L, 6L, 25L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L), Interaction = structure(list(
sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 12L, 
12L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(1L, 1L, 5L, 
11L, 11L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("PST", "PST", "PST", 
"PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), Start = structure(list(
sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), yday = c(59L, 59L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("PST", "PST", 
"PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST"
), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", 
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", 
"gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), Weeks = structure(c(-9, 
-9, -8, -7, -7, -9, -8, -8, -8, -8), units = "weeks", class = "difftime")), .Names = c("ID", 
"QUEUE", "Calls", "Interaction", "Start", "Weeks"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

To get around this problem, I want to calculate the difference in weeks between any interaction date (d1$Interaction) and the first interaction date in the system for that agent (d1$ID). How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (all in base R):

```
#split the data frame according to ID
mylist <- split(df, factor(df$ID))

#use do.call to combine lists elements to one data.frame
#instead of do call you can use data.table::rbindlist for speed
mydata <- do.call(rbind,
lapply(mylist, function(x) {
               #order each group
               x <- x[order(x$Interaction),]
               #calculate time differences
               #difftime of Interactions vector from the 2nd element to the last, minus
               #the Interactions vector of the 1st element to the penultimate
               #I use c(0, difftime.... to add a zero to the first difference
               #so that I can add it as a column
               x$weekdif <- c(0,difftime(x$Interaction[2:length(x$Interaction)],  
                            x$Interaction[1:(length(x$Interaction)-1)],
                            units='weeks'))
               x
}))
```

Output:

```
> mydata
          ID QUEUE Calls Interaction      Start    Weeks   weekdif
a123.1  a123  MSEP     1  2015-01-02 2015-03-01 -9 weeks 0.0000000
a123.2  a123  MSEK     4  2015-01-02 2015-03-01 -9 weeks 0.0000000
a123.3  a123  MSEE    25  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.5714286
a123.4  a123  MSED    14  2015-01-12 2015-03-01 -7 weeks 0.8571429
a123.5  a123  MNEM     6  2015-01-12 2015-03-01 -7 weeks 0.0000000
b123.6  b123  MMEF    25  2015-01-02 2015-03-01 -9 weeks 0.0000000
b123.7  b123  MMEM     5  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.5714286
b123.8  b123  MHEK     1  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.0000000
b123.9  b123  MMED     1  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.0000000
b123.10 b123  MMEM     3  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.0000000
```

I changed the function to the following and now it works as you want it:

```
#you need to import this for the na.locf function
library(zoo)

mylist <- split(df, factor(df$ID))
mydata <- do.call(rbind,
lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  x <- x[order(x$Interaction),]
  x$weekdif <- c(0,difftime(x$Interaction[2:length(x$Interaction)], x$Interaction[1:(length(x$Interaction)-1)], units='weeks'))
  #convert all zeros (apart from first to NAs)
  x$weekdif[x$weekdif==0] <- NA 
  #create the rolling values minus the first NAs
  #see the examples at ?na.locf for details on what it does
  temp <- as.numeric(na.locf(zoo(x$weekdif)))
  #add the first NAs
  missing_length <- length(x$weekdif) - length(temp)
  x$weekdif <- c(rep(0,missing_length), temp)
  x
}))
```

Output:

```
          ID QUEUE Calls Interaction      Start    Weeks   weekdif
a123.1  a123  MSEP     1  2015-01-02 2015-03-01 -9 weeks 0.0000000
a123.2  a123  MSEK     4  2015-01-02 2015-03-01 -9 weeks 0.0000000
a123.3  a123  MSEE    25  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.5714286
a123.4  a123  MSED    14  2015-01-12 2015-03-01 -7 weeks 0.8571429
a123.5  a123  MNEM     6  2015-01-12 2015-03-01 -7 weeks 0.8571429
b123.6  b123  MMEF    25  2015-01-02 2015-03-01 -9 weeks 0.0000000
b123.7  b123  MMEM     5  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.5714286
b123.8  b123  MHEK     1  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.5714286
b123.9  b123  MMED     1  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.5714286
b123.10 b123  MMEM     3  2015-01-06 2015-03-01 -8 weeks 0.5714286
```

First values for each id are 0 because there is no previous interaction date.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I might be receiving this error when I apply to my actual dataframe?

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "weekdif", value = c(0, NA, 0)) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1

Comment: The code should be able to run in any data frame that has an Interaction column. This is an assignment error which makes me think you made a mistake copying the code from above? without seeing the actual data or where the error occurs it is difficult to debug...

Comment: With this sample, could you tell me why the 4th (0.857) and 5th (0.000) rows for "weekdif" are different for the same ID and same Interaction date? They should both be 0.857, shouldn't they? I need a value in every row. Thanks.

Comment: Because it is calculating the difference of time (in weeks) between "any interaction date (d1$Interaction) and the first interaction date". So, if the ID and the Interaction date are the same there is a difference of 0 weeks. If you wanted all rows to be filled with the previous value if the ID and the Interaction Date are the same you should mention it in your question. Also, an output of what you want is usually appreciated by most users. I will work on fixing this later on.

Comment: Solution works except that it only provides a weekdif value for the first date that is different from the earliest date in the system. In example above, row 5, the interaction date is not the same as the earliest interaction date, it is 1/12/15 and the earliest interaction date is 1/2/15. The weekdif shows 0. It should be 0.8571429. There is a week value in every row of sample I provided so apologies that I didn't anticipate that it wouldn't be clear that I needed a value in every row. If correct value in every row, resolved.

Comment: I provided a new answer that will fix the problem.